# POST method Angular Reactive form data to API

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I have 8 simple input fields on my form. I want to post the data to the backend through API using POST method.

I have couple of ts files.

1. Register.ts

   ```
   export class User {
        public EmployeeName: string;
        public EmployeeID: string;
        public Department: string;
        public Location: string;
        public PhoneNumber: string;
        public Email: string;
   }
   ```
2. Register.Service.ts

   ```
   postUser() {             
       return this.http.post(`${this.apiUrl}/userdata`,  Register,this.httpOptions).toPromise().then((data: any) => {
         console.log(data);
         this.json = JSON.stringify(data.json);
       })
   }
   ```
3. Register.component.ts

   ```
   return this.httpService.postUser().then(data => {
        console.log(data);
   });
   ```

I am not getting any error also at the same thing nothing is happening. Please correct me.

HTML code

```
<form  #userForm (ngSubmit)="Submit()" >
    <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
                   <mat-label>Employee Name</mat-label>
                   <input matInput placeholder="Employee Name" required>
                </mat-form-field>
```

Comment: You are not returning in your then. Also, why use promises in the first place? And why are you setting this.json in your service? (And why stringify it?)

Comment: You say you're using reactive forms, but there is no code in your post showing this really the case. Include all the code needed to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using chrome you can check the network tab in the developer tools to see the response from the post request (https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network/reference)  or else you can try to put a catch to see if an exception is being returned.

```
return this.httpService.postUser()
.then(data => {console.log(data);})
.catch(err=>console.log(err));
```

Comment: I tried it and getting the following error. HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 400, statusText: "Bad Request", url: "http://localhost:4200/api/myapi", ok: false

Comment: do you have your backend server running on localhost:4200 ? most likely it would be on a different port

Comment: It is on a different port not on 4200. But I can see that this is not an issue for Get methods. It is happening only for POST

Comment: thats very strange .. i think you should prepend your host and port while making the post call  return this.http.post(`http://host:port /${this.apiUrl}/userdata`,

Comment: Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://10.1.1.1:81/api/myapi' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Comment: you will need to enable CORS on your server side

Comment: I did it at client side and it is working fine for all GET methods

Comment: can you please tell me how data is passing from component file to service ts file?

Comment: Yes just noticed you are not passing the data there .. i would imagine that you will need to pass the data while calling the function and also use it in the post call

Comment: Worth going through this https://www.positronx.io/how-to-use-angular-8-httpclient-to-post-formdata/

Comment: Will check and let you know. Thank you

Comment: const dummyData={
      "your-api-field-name":this.yourReactiveForm.value.yourAngularFieldName

Comment: Glad it worked .. do you mind marking it answered then.